# Specified SASL mechanism not supported net/imap ruby

Tags: ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2, imap, sasl

I am using ruby 1.9.3 for validating the email credentials using "net/imap" library.
If I try to use the following code in rails console it works :-

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.aol.com')
imap.authenticate('LOGIN', "username@aol.com".split("@").first, "password")
```

But when I use it in Rails application it gives me an error :-

```
Specified SASL mechanism not supported.
```

This happens only in case of AOL, yahoo is working in both console and rails app.

Does anyone have in insight what it could be.

Thanks

Comment: AOL doesn't support SASL Login.  How about using just plain LOGIN (not SASL).

Comment: AOL's capability string: `* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS ID NAMESPACE LOGIN-REFERRALS IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=XAOL-UAS-MB AUTH=OAUTH2 STARTTLS`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used imap.login in place of imap.authenticate.
It worked like a charm.

```
imap.login('user', 'passwd')
```